# Activate button onclick css effect with js

Tags: javascript, css

Im making a piano app using vanilla JS and have it so the piano keys can be clicked using the keyboard.
So that whenever certain keys are pressed on the keyboard, the corresponding button will be pressed.
But i also want the button click css effect to activate.

I managed to make the keyboard keys work using the .click() method, but this doesn't activate the button click css effect. Is there a way to do that?

this is what i have so far.

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.repeat) return

        switch (event.key) {
            case "a":
                document.getElementById("c4").click();
                break
            // then a bunch more cases for the rest of the keys
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]

Comment: I added som information to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
const a = document.getElementById("c4")


document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {

  switch (event.key) 
    case "a":
      a.click();
      a.classList.add("down")
```

and remove the class on keyUp

To save you some time, perhaps you can use this codepen I took over to add JS to it

https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/dyjLKYJ

I added keyboard events to it, but the :active pseudo class is not triggered on click.

---

A simpler alternative (I do not like switch):

Give each note element a class="note"

```
<button type="button" class="note">A</button>
<button type="button" class="note">B</button>
<button type="button" class="note">C</button>
```

then have

```
const notes = [...document.querySelectorAll(".note")].reduce((acc,cur) => {
  acc[cur.textContent.toLowerCase()] = cur;
  return acc
},{})

const validKeys = "abcdefg";
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const key = event.key;
  if (!validKeys.includes(key)) return;
  const note = notes[key];
  note.click();
  note.classList.add("down")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the button click CSS effect, you can manually add and remove a CSS class that corresponds to the click effect

You could implement this in your code :

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.repeat) return

    switch (event.key) {
        case "a":
            let c4 = document.getElementById("c4");
            c4.classList.add("clicked");
            setTimeout(() => {
                c4.classList.remove("clicked");
            }, 100);
            break
    }
});
```